# How to extract each words separated by comma in a text using Blue Prism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Given the string "House, Building, Farm, Office", how can I extract each word and store them in a collection in Blue Prism?

Answer (score 5):

Import the bundled `Utility - Strings` Business Object from `<Blue Prism install dir>/VBO/BPA Object - Utility - Strings.xml` and use the `Split Text` action to get each of the comma-separated strings as an individual collection row.

```
Object: Utility - Strings
Action: Split Text
Inputs:
    - Text to Split: <data item containing your comma-separated list>
    - Split Char: ", "
    - Collection Field Name: <string name of your choosing>
Outputs:
    - Split Values (single-column collection)
```

Comment: This approach is straightforward, but it breaks if one or more columns contain quotes and comma as value in it, such as `"12,000,000"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with code stage

```
Dim dt as DataTable = new DataTable
dt.columns.add("Values")
Dim dr as DataRow
Dim value as string
For each value in Input.Split(",")
    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0)=value
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
next value
Output = dt
```

Here `Input` is an input parameter to Code stage and `Output` is Output variable of Code Stage in Blue prism